# Visual Studio 15 not detecting Windows 10 SDK

Tags: visual-studio

Today I downloaded standalone installer for Windows 10 SDK which downloaded all the required files of about 700 MB. Then I installed it with a setup file placed within downloaded content. But still Visual Studio is showing:

[image]

Restarted PC also. Windows Software Dev Kit is listed under Programs and Features means it's installed properly.  When I Modify the installation of Visual Studio 2015, it starts downloading from installer.  Please help

Comment: Did you find any solution about this problem. I have exactly same problem .

Comment: @mayk no, i had to redownload sdk from within VS setup

Comment: Thanks for answer. i have tried both redownloading sdk and repairing visual studio but still i dont solve my problem. I have tried offline installer of sdk also.